# iText merge, scale and rotate pages in existing pdf

Tags: pdf, itext

I want to concat existing pdf and also scale and rotate them to A4 portrait pages. Today i have done this with pdfWriter:

```
for (int pageNum = 1; pageNum <= numberOfPages; pageNum++) {
    PdfImportedPage importedPage = writer.getImportedPage( reader, pageNum );
    AffineTransform transform = getAffineTransform(reader, writer, pageNum);
    pdfContentByte.addTemplate(importedPage, transform);
    document.newPage();
}


private AffineTransform getAffineTransform(PdfReader reader, PdfWriter writer, int pageNum) {
    Rectangle readerPageSize = reader.getPageSize( pageNum );
    Rectangle writerPageSize = writer.getPageSize();

    float rPageHeight = readerPageSize.getHeight();
    float rPageWidth = readerPageSize.getWidth();

    float wPageHeight = writerPageSize.getHeight();
    float wPageWidth = writerPageSize.getWidth();

    int pageRotation = reader.getPageRotation( pageNum );

    boolean rotate = (rPageWidth > rPageHeight) && (pageRotation == 0 || pageRotation == 180);
    if(!rotate)
        rotate = ((rPageHeight > rPageWidth) && (pageRotation == 90 || pageRotation ==270));
    //if changing rotation gives us better space rotate an extra 90 degrees.
    if(rotate) pageRotation += 90;
    double randrotate = (double)pageRotation * Math.PI/(double)180;

    AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
    float margin = 0;
    float scale = 1.0f;
    if(pageRotation == 90 || pageRotation == 270 ){
        scale = Math.min((wPageHeight - 2 * margin) / rPageWidth, (wPageWidth- 2 * margin) / rPageHeight);
    } else {
        scale = Math.min(wPageHeight / rPageHeight, wPageWidth / rPageWidth);
    }

    transform.translate((wPageWidth/2) + margin, wPageHeight/2 + margin);
    transform.rotate(-randrotate);
    transform.scale(scale,scale);
    transform.translate(-rPageWidth/2,-rPageHeight/2);
    return transform;
}
```

This works fine, but removes layers (OCG) and annotations.
Is it possible to get this to work with layers (OCG) and annotations? This is used for print, so I only need the pdf to display the same, I don't actually need the layers or annotations.

Comment: I'll need to check, but if appearance is all you care about, you can flatten the pdf first using PdfStamper. PdfStamper#setXXXFlattening(true). Alternatively, these kinds of operations should be easier in iText7: http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/chapter-6-reusing-existing-pdf-documents

Comment: setXXFlattening(true) seems to work. Too much code at the moment to upgrade to itext7 and also every time i change something in the pdf code something always breaks.

Comment: well, looking at your code you seem to be working with a  lot of low-level methods (directly using a PdfWriter as well as PdfContentByte is a giveaway), and those generally lead to a quite fragile code base unless you're absolutely sure of what you're doing. I'd advise you to use objects that exist on a higher level of abstraction such as PdfCopy, but I'd need to check if you can combine it with the rotation requirement.